# Will win8 boot if I disable UEFI?

Tags: windows-8, uefi

I'd like to disable UEFI mode in case if something will go wrong with my laptop and I will need to load another OS to it. However it would be very unfortunate if switching of UEFI prevented win8 from booting.

Does anybody know if it is safe to disable UEFI junk?

Comment: UEFI isn't really junk...it allows you computer to stop pretending its 1999.

Comment: Why do you want to disable UEFI now in case you may want to boot some legacy OS at some point in the future? (I'm not sure disabling UEFI is actually even a thing, I guess you would rather enable [CSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#CSM_booting))

Comment: The only way I found to get into BIOS is through windows Shift-Restart; ordinary restart with F1 did not let me get into BIOS. I do not know what will happen if Windows go down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed the OS when UEFI was enabled, then your system disk uses a [GUID Partition Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table).

**BIOS can't boot from these partitions**, and even if it could, your current system installation has no BIOS-compatible bootloader, so you would just be stuck on a black screen right after the BIOS if you disabled UEFI.

If you still want to disable it, you'd have to reinstall your system and reformat your system disk, however there is no need to disable UEFI if you system works fine with it, which I assume it does.